# List all used variables of formulas of a latex document

Tags: equations

in the first pages of my thesis I have to list all Greek and Latin letters of constants and variables. Is there a way to run through the hole document and create that list? I don't need that list to appear inside the document itself.

I tried to research this, but didn't find any solution that would go through all equations and formulas between dollars signs and generate the list.

If there's nothing out there, I think about solving this for me in python. Read my .tex files and search. In that case I will share it here.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Geez.  This seems like a headache.  If you use a consistent naming convention, then perhaps you'll be able to find things easily.  But, as in my own thesis, to save typing, I had things buried inside macros.  What about standard contants like `e`, `i`, or `pi`, do those too need to be listed?  And if this list doesn't appear in the document itself, what purpose does this list serve?

Comment: The purpose is to not miss one constant or variable. So the list can be ugly af ;-) It should just help me not to miss any of them. Standard constants are not necessary for me.

Comment: There is the `nomencl` package for that, `\usepackage{nomencl}`. It won't find out which symbols you have used but it will create the list of symbols for you if you say in your document what you want to put in. A good strategy is to always add the symbol whenever you are using it first, together with an equation, I use  `\refeqpage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Hi, this is [Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094) replying as Psmith, the TeX bot. The reason for this answer is that this particular account needs at least 20 reputation which is needed to being able to talk in the chatroom.*</sup>

Sadly, little to nothing can be done in this situation other than using a script and some pesky regular expressions to locate math symbols in your document. Worse: even after a proper symbol extraction, semantics must be manually specified.

I think most of us found the hard way that post-processing is indeed a can of worms. If I may, a word of advice: since it is an important document – your thesis – I personally believe the manual extraction can bring some practical benefits to you, such as a closer proofreading and also improvements in the rethorics. Sometimes, an semi-automatic solution might give us faster results at the risk of missing important elements. Of course, your mileage might vary greatly.

[As mr. marmot said in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455171/list-all-used-variables-of-formulas-of-a-latex-document#comment1144793_455171), there are some packages that can help you to document your symbols and then generate a proper list at the end. My personal take is with the `glossaries` package, which can easily handle a list of symbols for you.

Comment: Just a quick note: I will not upvote this answer since it is pretty much me with another account. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: ooh a duck

Comment: Pwelcome pto pTeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. This shows again that not always a technical solution is the best. Still, at the end I will double check by extraction all the formulas. That’s probably the best.

Comment: @programmar: my pleasure, and good luck with your thesis! TeX is a bit tricky regarding syntax, but a usually well-behaved document does not yield too much unexpected surprises. `:)`

Comment: It’s my third time with Tex. I love it!